# Alternative to perl unpack in c++

Tags: c++, perl

I have the below piece of code in Perl which needs to be converted to C++?

```
 my $uint32;
 my $n = read( $psf{FH_PSF}, $uint32, 4 );
 unpack_big_endian( 'I', $uint32 );

 unpack_big_endian function: 
   my ( $pack, $chunk ) = @_;

    # PSF always big-endian
    unpack( $pack, $byte_order == $LITTLE_ENDIAN ? reverse($chunk) : $chunk );
```

The data file is already packed using perl code and is there any c++ utility which can be used to unpack this data?

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but i have a data file in which the data is already packed using perl ,can it be unpacked using libpack utility ?

Comment: Perl's pack/unpack and libpack don't impose any policy on how your data is encoded, they simply provide a mechanism for you to encode it any way you wish. So yes, in that sense, they are compatible.

Comment: FILE *fp;
 fp=fopen("transient1.tran", "r");
 
 if(fp == NULL)
 {
   int errno = 0;
   printf("file pointer is null %d",errno);
 }

 fseek(fp,-4,SEEK_END);
 if(fp == NULL)
 {
   int errno = 0;
   printf("file pointer is null %d",errno);
 }
 
 int len = ftell(fp);
 printf("the value of len is %d",len);
 
 
 int value_a;
 //printf("the value of a is %d",value_a);
 value_a = funpack(fp,"u32");
 printf("the value of a is %d",value_a);  output:End of template while looking for endian declaration
the value of len is 438328Abort

Comment: i have run the above code and as u can see in the output,it aborts on a call to funpack(),any thing wrong ?

Comment: I suggest opening a chat or an email instead for further support; comments aren't really the place to do that.